# Can't understand onPress behaviour TouchableOpacity by calling function in different ways

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a react-native class component, in which I have a counter function:

```
counter() {
  console.log("hi")
  this.setState({count:this.state.count+1})
}
```

I have a state named count initialized to 0.
I have a text which displays the count value as well.

In my render, in the return, im trying to call this counter function onPress of a TouchableOpacity. I tried 2 things in the onPress with 2 different outputs. Can someone explain why i got these outputs for each case? :

1. onPress = {() => this.counter()}

here, state value was updating and displaying, and i got the console.log as well (desired output)

2. onPress = {this.counter}

here, i got the console.log, but the state value wasn't updating. why isnt state updating here?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try to console value of count inside counter function and update the question.

Comment: You can try this to update your state , this.setState(prevState=>({...prevState,count:prevState.count+1}))

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call counter function without arrow pattern in class component then you need to call bind in constructor block for counter function

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.counter = this.counter.bind(this);
}

counter() {
    this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 });
}
```

Comment: If you're starting out with react native, I'd highly suggest that you use functional components instead of class components so that you don't have to deal with the stuff mentioned in this answer.

Comment: @RodSar Yes i agree but it's what i tried to answer that asked why it's not working.

Comment: @RodSar i know many ppl have recommended functional comps to me, but i find class components easier... guess im different because everyone else finds functional components easier

Comment: I agree that class components are easier to read during the first couple of days of using react, but once you go a little deeper and start dealing with (this), and binding and requiring the use of hooks then functional components will save you a lot of this hassle (which is the reason they are recommended by everyone)